# Where is the Android Reference Monitor & Package Manager located in the Android Software Stack?

Tags: android

While studying Android, I have seen the Android software stack. Having come across multiple sources it is confusing to me where these two components are in the 4 layered software stack.

Android Software Stack: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_architecture.htm

Comment: What is `Android Reference Monitor`? `Package Manager` is right in the picture provided, i.e. on the framework level (Java written).

Comment: I get the Package manager. But where is the reference monitor? There is a resource manager but no reference monitor...